# Изменить функцию с побочными эффектами на pure function

Tags: javascript

Функция changeEven(numbers, value) принимает массив чисел numbers и обновляет каждый элемент, значение которого это чётное число, добавляя к нему значение параметра value.

Выполнить рефакторинг функции так, чтобы она стала чистой - не изменяла массив чисел numbers, а создавала, наполняла и возвращала новый массив с обновлёнными значениями.

```
function changeEven(numbers, value) {
  // Change code below this line
  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i += 1) {
    if (numbers[i] % 2 === 0) {
      numbers[i] = numbers[i] + value;
    }
  }
}
```

мой вариант

```js
function changeEven(numbers, value) {

  const newArray = [];
  numbers.forEach(element => {
    if (numbers % 2 === 0) {
      newArray.push(element + value)
    }

  });
  return newArray
}

console.log(changeEven([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 10))
console.log(changeEven([17, 24, 68, 31, 42], 100))
```

что мне нужно добавит(изменить)?

Comment: А что сейчас не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо заменить это:

```
if (numbers % 2 === 0) {
```

на это:

```
if (element % 2 === 0) {
```

---

а также дописать:

```
else newArray.push(element)
```

чтобы вставлять неизменённые нечётные элементы в массив

Comment: По-моему ему надо ещё дописать `else newArray.push(element)`. Хотя в "грязной" ф-ии тоже нет `else`, странно... А, там и не надо, там автоматом это выполняется :)

Comment: @EzioMercer ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  вот и я не знаю. Пока остановился на "очепятке"

Comment: Не, это точно) В грязной ф-ии `else` не нужен потому что затрягиваются только чётные числа. А для нового массива их надо вручную вставлять

Comment: Окей) Да будет так

Comment: спасибо за дополнение.